Negative binomial GLM with interaction term...Anova warning?
I am running a seemingly simple model:
model<- glm.nb(PathogenLoad ~ Species*Lifestage, data = data)

The species variable has 3 levels and Lifestage has 2 levels. Everything seems to run fine on the model itself, except when I try to run an ANOVA (anova(model)) I get the output with the following warning message.
          Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev Pr(>Chi)    
NULL                                 96      256.4             
Lifestage          1      0.0        95     7152.5        1    
Species            2   3220.2        93     3932.4   <2e-16 ***
Lifestage:Species  2   3793.0        91      139.4   <2e-16 ***

**Warning messages:
1: In anova.negbin(nb_model) : tests made without re-estimating 'theta'
2: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
3: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge **

I have been looking everywhere and am just uncertain if this means that my model is actually not working or if it is simply because Anovas are complicated to run on glm.nb?
What I am hoping to see is the independent and interactive effects as clearly as when I ran the car:: Anova on a different binary model.
Is there another way to do this I don't know about for glm.nb? Or is it ok to use emmeans and just interpret my data without the ANOVA? Is it possible I need to try a different family for my overdispersed data?

For lifestage you have a deviance of 0 and a p value of 1. Something is weird there, but I am not sure what. Have you looked at a crosstabl of lifestage and species? Also, you could make a plot of pathogen load for each of the six combinations. Also, I don't think the first warning is of particular concern.

@PeterFlom Thanks for getting back to me. Could it be because I only have one tadpole life stage for one of the species? Overall, tadpoles were infected less so there are less of this life stage than adults in the data.
Is it usually possible to run anova on glm.nb ?

Did you take a look at the documentation for MASS::anova.negbin? It explains the warning. Though that doesn't mean the model fits your data well in the first place.

Yes, that could definitely be it.
